# sentry logback saves only last log

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

my app sends only last log to sentry

```
@Slf4j
public class Opp implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Opp.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    log.error("hello world to sentry");
    log.error("hello world Mickey Mouse");
    log.error("hi there!");
    log.debug("what upp science b!");
    log.warn("what upp science b!");
}
```

}

I have 5 logs but in dashboard I can see only last one [image: dashboard screenshot]

How to configure it to log all logs?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="SENTRY" class="com.getsentry.raven.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <dsn>***</dsn>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="SENTRY" />
</root>
```

Comment: Hmm, how is the `log` variable defined?

Comment: And also can you ensure they aren't being incorrectly grouped? Are the other logs showing up as individual events in that first group from your picture?

Comment: @Brett log variable was defined via Slf4j annotation (lombok)  

nope I can see only last log

Comment: hmm weird I can see logs(error, warn) now except debug.

but they were grouped as events and my last log as issue. @Brett

Comment: I think this may be related to: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/issues/396

Comment: @Brett it helped me thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it aggregates logs/events on method level. If you open logged record you can see number of logged events (Click on number).